# Removing elements from a map of type (Int, ListBuffer(Int))

Tags: scala, linkedhashmap, listbuffer

I have `LinkedHashMap`s of type:

`val map1 = LinkedHashMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> (1,2), 3 -> (1,2,3))
val map2 = LinkedHashMap(2 -> 2, 3 -> (2,3), 5 -> (2,3,5))`

where the integers are nodes's ids of a graph, and the list is the path to that node. I want to implement the case of deleting a node. Suppose I want to delete node 3, I have to do two actions: remove the element with key = 3 in every map, remove the elements which have 3 in their list. How to do it in scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define you map like you have,

```
val map1 = LinkedHashMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> (1,2), 3 -> (1,2,3))
```

You do not have `key: Int` and `value: List[Int]` but you have `key: Int` and `values: Any`.

```
scala> val map1 = LinkedHashMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> (1,2), 3 -> (1,2,3))
// map1: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,Any] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> (1,2), 3 -> (1,2,3))
```

To match your requirement, you should define your map like following,

```
scala> val map1 = LinkedHashMap(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(1,2), 3 -> List(1,2,3))
// map1: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(1, 2), 3 -> List(1, 2, 3))
```

Now, if you want to delete a node `3`,

```
scala> val map2 = map1.filter({
     |   case (key, list) => key != 3 && !list.contains(3)
     | })
// map2: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(1, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you! What if my LinkedHashMap is a vertex attribute in the graph? To delete a node 3 from every node's map I have to go with something like: 
`graph.vertices.filter({
      |   case (key,list) => key != 3 && !list.contains(3)
        | })`
but it's not the right syntax.

Comment: obviously vertices are of type `val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]])]`